# How to disable all active record validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I need to disable active record validations on all existing models, is there an easy way to accomplish this?

EDIT:
Since I am warned not to do it here is the reason: its in my pet project, someone else added validations and seed stoped to work. Due limited time every evening, I wanted to code, not to focus on editing quite complex seed.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to do so? Because removing every validations will allow your end-users to create non-consistent records, like User without a username/password/email, and can lead to non-fixable issues

Comment: I added reason in question

Comment: you reason is so bad. sorry, so your seeds are wrong or your validations. you should either get one back on track instead of disabling.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of a way to disable validations globally, but on a per instance basis, you can disable validations when calling `save` by saying `model.save(validate: false)`

Comment: Thanks, I anwsered myself - in order to share knowledge, upvote if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job:

```
module ActiveModel
  module Validations
    def valid?(*)
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would do this. Why would you have validations defined in the first place if you plan on disabling globally?

Comment: I added reason in question

Comment: just put the def valid? into your model to disable it for ONE model, not globally